# ASP.NET core styles on linux deployment

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Developed  a hello word in ASP.NET Core,
 an application windows "VS_17"
.

I then published code and deployed in Linux Apache server.
I am able to see the website but no styles, bootstrap are reflects in the site.
I could see the reference in developer tool.

Like this

```
"src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js" "
```

It tried giving Linux folders static path also.

Any help please its taking more time.

Comment: Have you checked the css files urls in developer tool network tab? What happens when you try to access the css file(s) directly using the browser?

Comment: network result is 404, src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" this is the code i used . publised code has lib under wwwroot in linux server. i tried to access the publised site from machine http://servername/port ...asp.net core app

Comment: any update please

Comment: i have tried also setting content root directory in application Iwebhost

Comment: worked issue is with content root directory

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to add this in Program.cs:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseKestrel()
                      .UseContentRoot(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
                      .UseUrls("http://*:6056")
                      .UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
                
    }
```

AND to deploy the application with the script as shown in this [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69292799/7873901)
Application was deployed on RockyLinux, with no nginx
Inspired by this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62564190/unable-to-load-static-files-from-net-core-web-app-using-ubuntu-apache)